# Shapefiles of Central America and Mexico coastlines?

Tags: data, mexico

Where can I find a shapefile of Central America + Mexico (WSG84) (with no administrative boundaries) at a low resolution?

I'm looking for a very simple shapefile without the small islands and smoothed out coastlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three common methods to get shapefiles of your region of interest.

1. [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-admin-0-countries/).  Select the areas of interest > export to new
   shapefile > dissolve
2. [Natural Earth Coastlines](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110m-coastline/)
3. [Global ADMN](http://www.gadm.org/country). Merge the countries of interest > Dissolve

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4fb555ebe4b04cb937751db9) is a link to the North American political boundaries.  You can [dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the entire layer to make it on multi-part polygon.

*Updated link - 2021-02*

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find coastline data at different resolutions and quality stages: [A Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution Geography Database](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg).

Answer (score 0):

Frequently updated OpenStreetMap data licensed under OdbL might be an option for you. They can be downloaded from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines in WGS84

Answer (score -1):

You will find Mexican shapefile free to download at [Effortless Online GIS Mapping - Mexico shapefile](https://www.igismap.com/download-mexico-shapefile-free-boundary-line-polygon/).
You can also convert this shapefile in KML or CSV